# Boostrap style link in table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have a pretty easy question but not sure why I cant figure it out.

I have a table that I am creating and it's `tr` has a class of `info`.

I am trying to see that in the table, I want all links inside of a `tr` with the `class` of active to be `white`.

This is my table:

```
<table id="note_5" class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="info">
         <td class="col-md-3"><small><a target="_BLANK" href="http://xxy">Carl Hussey</a></small></td>
         <td class="col-md-3"><small>06/05/2015</small></td>
         <td class="col-md-3"><small>x</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
            <p>sdsfsdf</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
.table > thead > tr > td.info,
.table > tbody > tr > td.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.info,
.table > thead > tr > th.info,
.table > tbody > tr > th.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.info,
.table > thead > tr.info > td,
.table > tbody > tr.info > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > td,
.table > thead > tr.info > th,
.table > tbody > tr.info > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > th 
.table > tbody > tr.info > td > a:link 
.table > tbody > tr.info > td > a:active 
.table > tbody > tr.info > td > a:hover {
  background-color: #009CDE;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Am I close? The link just remains its primary color and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why don't you just create a class for just the link, and apply !important to the CSS?

Comment: Is the class of "active" meant to belong to the tr or to the a? I do not see it present in your example.

Comment: Active is meant for the `TR` so it gives it the background color.

Comment: Your CSS is missing commas in between the last few selectors, so those rules are probably not targeting what you think they are

Comment: Nice catch @BlakeMann, I added them but it still didn't change them I'm afraid.